# Flot Chart issue with x axis

Tags: jquery, flot

I have an application where a user can search on data over a date range.  I am using Flot charts and I am using the time mode.  I have

```
$.plot($('#graph-lines'), graphData, {
        series: {
            points: {
                show: true,
                radius: 5
            },
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            shadowSize: 0
        },
        grid: {
            color: '#646464',
            borderColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 20,
            hoverable: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            //tickColor: 'transparent',
            //tickDecimals: 2, 
            show: true,
             mode: "time",
             minTickSize: [1, options["TimeInterval"]],
             twelveHourClock : false,
             min: new Date(options["GraphMinXValue"]),
             max: new Date(options["GraphMaxXValue"])
        }
```

I am setting the min and max values of the graph to be the start date of the date range and end date of the date range.  The time interval will be "hour" or "day" depending on what the user selects.  My question is when I search for a week range at an hourly level I need to display every half hour per tick and each tick needs to have enough spacing between them. I.e.  DateStart = '12-12-2013', EndDate = '19-12-2013' zoom = "hour". Graph x axis needs to show:

```
12-12-2013 00:00   00:30   01:00   01:30 ....     13-12-2013 00:00
```

What options do I need to set?  Do I need to override the ticks to achieve this? If so how do I set the spacing between the ticks and allow overflow.

Comment: The question has not been answered

Comment: You asked the exact same question again, rather than editing your existing one.  Whether it's answered or not, it's a duplicate.